# How can I automatically lower Spotify playback volume when my Video Editing program makes a sound?

Tags: video, audio, editing, volume-mixer

I'd like to listen to Spotify while I am video editing.  This is just casual listening - nothing to do with the editing work.

How can I automatically fade out the volume of Spotify when my video editing program plays audio?  I often need to hear the video editing audio without the distraction of Spotify playing over the top, but the video editing playback is too on/off/on/off to switch Spotify audio manually each time.  Without background music, I get really sick of the repeated playback of the audio clips with only silence inbetween.

I suppose what I needd is an app that monitors sound output from 'App A' and reduces the sound output from all others (Apps B, C, D, etc) when something is played.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically, at least without putting in some work to reconfigure the video editor and the program.

The underlying goal and features I think you'll be (creatively) utilizing are the Windows Communication Monitor (I don't know what else to call it), to adjust the volume of all other programs when your video program makes noise.

Open Audio Devices and Sound Themes by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **Hardware and Sound**, and then clicking **Sound** then clicking on the **communications** tab.

Then choose the volume reduction level (eg. 80%).

[image: Communications tab of Sound dialog in Windows 7]

What you'll need to do is essentially this:

1. Download and install a virtual speaker or sound card. (search [Google](http://google.com) for VSC or something similar to find VSC software.  I stumbled upon [Virtual Audio Streaming](http://www.virtualaudiostreaming.net/),  which might just do the trick.
2. Configure your video editor to use the virtual speaker as the default playback option.
3. Download and install a virtual audio cable (optional if the VSC or similar software can automatically route the audio stream).  A simple [Google](http://google.com) search turned up [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm).
4. Download and install a virtual microphone.
5. Send the audio from the VSC (step 1&2) to the virtual microphone (step 4).

   after you've done all this...
6. Open Sound by clicking the **Start** button , and then clicking **Control Panel**. In the search box, type **sound**, and then click **Sound**.
7. Click the **Recording** tab, click (the virtual)**Microphone**, and then click **Properties**.
8. click the **Listen** tab, click the **Listen to this device** check box, ensure that the *playback through this device* is set to your **real speaker** and then click **OK**.

What <strike>should</strike> will happen is the sound from the video editing program will be perceived as communication, so Windows will automatically reduce the volume of all other programs (internet browser for example, with your music stream), and you'll be happier.

Comment: This looks fantastic.  I am not sure why it took me so long to find you had answered.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible automatically. But I use a program called AutoHotkey that allows you to set up hotkey commands, and is incredibly flexible at that. Windows 7 already has a built in mixer with different levels for each program, you may be able to assign a hotkey to toggle the volume for spotify if it is running.

AHK has a little bit of a learning curve because it is essentially a type of scripting language. But, they made it pretty simple and there are lots of tutorials. Hope this helps.